# Get Hex Of Cell Colours

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, colors, hex, google-sheets-formula

I've been researching how to get the Hex value of the colour of a cell in a pasted in sheet into Google Sheets.

I need to assign a value to a specific colour - eg, red 1, amber 2, green 3 blue 4!

From this style paste in!

[image: Example From Pasted Data]

I've tried the following code (copy /paste from the online tutorials) but i cant get it to run at all?

All i get is the error code in the 2nd picture below

```
function getHex(input) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(input).getBackgrounds();
}
```

I've literally copy / pasted it and it doesn't work?

Sorry I'm such a Newbie when it comes to Script editing!

The Error i get shows as

Range not Found (line2, file "Code")

All help greatly received!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paste your script into script editor, save it, authorize it... then use formula with cell reference:

```
=GETHEX("A3")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Awesome thank you!

So i literally had it - But i was expecting there to be another step in between saving the code and it working in the code!

Comment: Can i Further this by having it automatically recalculate when a new colour is pasted into the target cell?

Comment: 99% sure you can't unless you play with triggers or macro